# ADAL.NET ID-Token from logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, adal

I have an webapplication which uses the Microsoft Graph API to get data from Office365 services. For the login i took the code from Microsofts sample project, which uses ADAL.NET Library for authentification.

When i make an http request it checks if the a request was authentificated. The problem is, when a new session was started no authetification request was performed, although the user is logged in. I get the error message **Error Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken**.

After research i found out that i have to call the Method **AcquireTokenSilentlyAsync()**, which verifies if an acceptable token is in the cache. I have implemented this method but it always throws an exception. After debugging i saw that there is no ID-Token when a logged in user makes an request. How can i get this ID-Token?

```
public static AuthProvider Instance { get; } = new AuthProvider();

        // Get an access token. First tries to get the token from the token cache.
        public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            HttpContextBase httpContextBase = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase;

            SessionTokenCache tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID, httpContextBase);
            var cachedItems = tokenCache.ReadItems(); // see what's in the cache

            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, tokenCache);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);

            string userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            UserIdentifier userId = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

            try
            {
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.GraphResourceId, clientCredential, userId);
                return result.AccessToken;
            }
            // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                throw new Exception("Error" + $" {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

```
    public class SessionTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private HttpContextBase context;
        private static readonly object FileLock = new object();
        private readonly string CacheId = string.Empty;
        public string UserObjectId = string.Empty;

        public SessionTokenCache(string userId, HttpContextBase context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.UserObjectId = userId;
            this.CacheId = UserObjectId + "_TokenCache";

            AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            Load();
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                Deserialize((byte[])context.Session[CacheId]);
            }
        }

        public void Persist()
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                // Reflect changes in the persistent store.
                var bytes = Serialize();
                var x = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                context.Session[CacheId] = Serialize();

                // After the write operation takes place, restore the HasStateChanged bit to false.
                HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please let us know what is the Authentication flow you are using?

Comment: Hello, I use OAuth 2.0 with the OpenID Connect.

Comment: please go through github [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect) which can help

Comment: Hello, this link doesnt work.

Comment: working for me.Please check again in another browser.

Comment: Hi Johnwix,please let us know if the issue is already fixed or still looking for any solution.

Comment: Hello Hari Krishna, i am still looking for an solution. I found out that there are multiple login solutions ADAL and MSAL. According to Microsoft the MSAL solution is the newer recommended. Should i use MSAL instead of ADAL?

Comment: Yes, MSAL is recommended since ADAL is going to be depreciated.

Comment: Fixed my Issue using MSAL instead of ADAL.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will update it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the  [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect)  which helps in how to use MSAL.NET (Microsoft Authentication Library) to obtain an access token and will fix your issue.

> **Note:-** MSAL is recommended since ADAL is going to be depreciated